# How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash or disable the feature?

Tags: unity, gnome-shell, amazon, shopping-lens

How can I disable Amazon search results in the Dash?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Ubuntu 17.10** (and then **18.04**) has brought a few changes (for prior versions, see one of the other answers). There are no longer any Amazon/web search results when you search in the Dash, but the Amazon icon remains in the launcher by default. It is part of the [ubuntu-web-launchers](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/main/ubuntu-web-launchers) package, which can be removed with:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-web-launchers
```

At the time of this writing, Amazon appears to be the only thing in the package, so it should be fine to remove. Keep in mind that this might not be the case in the future, so it might be safer to just remove Amazon if you might want to keep other web launchers. Take a look at the [list of files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/ubuntu-web-launchers/filelist) in the package and get rid of the Amazon ones:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/com.canonical.launcher.amazon.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

Answer (score 239):

Click on the Ubuntu button, search for "Privacy" and then turn off "Include online results" :

[image]

You can also remove it entirely by clicking on this button, then the orange "Available on the Ubuntu Software Center" button and selecting uninstall:

[image: Remove via the software center]

or via the command line

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

You then need to log out and back in.

Another option would be to move the lens entirely out of the home dash and make it a standalone lens:

- [How can I move Amazon search results into a dedicated shopping lens and out of the home lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-move-amazon-search-results-into-a-dedicated-shopping-lens-and-out-of-t)
- [I have permanent connections to Canonical servers, what are they for and how can I turn them off?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135602/i-have-permanent-connections-to-canonical-servers-what-are-they-for-and-how-can/145384#145384)

Comment: please make sure that u mention that this doesn't work for the latest version of ubuntu source http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/how-to-disable-amazon-shopping.html

Comment: To make this work with ubuntu 14.04, 14.10, and 15.04 run the following in terminal: gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"

Answer (score 78):

If you don't want online shopping results in your dash but there are times when you want to search the Internet from your queries (for example, while using the Askubuntu scope to the help lens), you may not wish to disable the "Include online search results" item. In that case you may wish to remove particular sources.

## For Ubuntu 13.04 and Earlier

### Home Lens

*For the new dash home lens (default) queries that are forwarded through Canonical to Amazon* uninstall [unity-lens-shopping](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity-lens-shopping)[image: Install unity-lens-shopping].

Either click on the bag icons above and click the `Remove` button on the right in the Software Center window that appears, or use an alternative of the following command line after bringing up a terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

Or, launch Ubuntu Software Center, click Installed, expand Themes & Tweak, and scroll to the its end. You'll see *Shopping lens for unity* there (along with a lot of complaints).

### Video Lens

*For the already existing video lens lookup* you can choose the source of searches by using the "Filter Results" item on the top right, and then selecting the sources you want by using the *Sources* drop down. Alternatively you can uninstall [unity-scope-video-remote](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity-scope-video-remote)[image: Install unity-scope-video-remote].

Either click on the bag icons above and click the `Remove` button on the right in the Software Center window that appears, or use the following command line after bringing up a terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-scope-video-remote
```

### Music Lens

*As in existing releases, online shopping for music in 12.10 can also go to the Ubuntu One Music Store.* To remove that feature click on the bag button for [unity-scope-musicstores](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity-scope-musicstores)[image: Install unity-scope-musicstores] and click on the `Remove` button on the right in the Ubuntu Software Center window that appears.

or enter the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-scope-musicstores
```

## For Ubuntu 13.10 and Later

(From http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/how-to-disable-amazon-shopping.html)

Go to the Dash by Pressing the Super-A key combination. For PC hardware the [Super key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_%28keyboard_button%29) may be the one that has the somewhat familiar computer company logo on it.

Click on "Filter" on the upper right of the dash, and then on "Type" right below. Then click on Dash Plugins to display them.

By clicking on the plugins of interest on the left you can get a summary of each plugin, including the Amazon one. You can disable or enable them individually with the button that appears below the summary.

For enhanced privacy the source for this answer suggests the following list for consideration.

> "Amazon, Ebay, Music Store, Popular Tracks Online, Skimlinks, Ubuntu
> One Music Search and Ubuntu Shop."

I would add the Ubuntu One Music Store, and Remote Videos as well.

There may be other plugins you don't care for as well, particularly since there are now a great number of scopes and many may forward your interests to sites you haven't vetted.

[unity-lens-applications](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity-lens-applications)[image: Install unity-lens-applications]  must be installed for this approach to work.

Usually when you bring up the dash you start with the **Home** lens. You can adjust what is searched by altering the Filter settings on the upper right of the dash before you starting type your search term.

Answer (score 26):

This has changed from previous versions where all you had to do was

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

However that does not work with 13.10 (and presumably later versions when they are released).

Ubuntu 13.10 does not have the shopping lens any more but now has [Smart Scopes](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/unity-smart-scopes-feature-lands-in.html) instead.

To disable a dash plug-in,  From the dash select filter results then "Dash plugins"

[image]

To disable a plugin, click on it and then click the "Disable" button.  You can re-enable it later if you want.

---

You can also disable all these plugins from the command line with

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

<sub>Source here:[How To Disable Amazon / Shopping Suggestions And Other Unity Scopes In Ubuntu 13.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/how-to-disable-amazon-shopping.html)</sub>

---

This stops the scope running but does not remove it from the dash

If you want to do this first unlock it from the launcher by right clicking it and selecting "unlock from launcher".

You will still be able to search for it in the dash but you can remove it from there too.

You need to run nautilus as root to do this See my answer to this question [Why is gksu no longer installed by default in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/284306/107450) for instructions on installing gksu or a workaround to run GUI apps as root.

You can now run the file manager with `gksudo nautilus`

Naviigate to `/usr/share/applications` find the file with the amazon logo and delete it.

Finally reboot and its gone for good.

Comment: So i can't remove Amazon app icon from dash ? I mean this icon [link](http://goo.gl/Fdv8Ox)

Comment: Yes you can get rid of the icon too I've edited my post to explain how.

Comment: The icon belongs to the package unity-webapps-common, which you can verify with 'dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop'. Then uninstall that package rather than just removing the file. (sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-common)

Comment: doesn't seem to have any effect on my Ubuntu 13.10. Patryk's answer contains some extra stuff though—these seem to have done the job.

Answer (score 12):

With [Privacy Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/indicator-privacy/) you can quickly enable or disable online results:

[image: Screenshot of Privacy Indicator]

Comment: Tested, works in 14.04

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the other answers, you can also redirect the queries to another location by changing the URL it uses for the product search:

```
sudo -s
echo 'OFFERS_URI="https://localhost:0/"' >> /etc/environment
```

And then restart your session.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure about the implications of this solutions but after removing shopping lens from Ubuntu 13.10 and higher (presumably)

```
sudo apt-get remove -y unity-lens-shopping
```

and disabling the scopes

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

as well as disabling remote search (this way your searches won't be sent to some remote location)

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search none
```

you can also manually remove the link from dash ( please comment if this is the correct way or there is a better way of doing this )

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

In 14.04 LTS, I was able to uninstall the Amazon application by:

1. opening Dash
2. searching for "Amazon"
3. right clicking the Amazon application icon
4. selecting "Delete" from the application's description

Answer (score 3):

IF you want to have a Ubuntu LiveCD without Amazon stuff there is a remastering script: http://www.helplinux.ru/wiki/en:kb:make-ubuntu-safe

Comment: Update: if you want to have a Ubuntu LiveCD with disabled online search results by default there is a new remastering script for this: http://www.helplinux.ru/wiki/en:kb:make-ubuntu-privacy-friendly

Answer (score 2):

This command lists all the scope files that can be disabled:

```
find /usr/share/unity/scopes/ -name \*.scope -printf "'%P',"|sed -es':/:-:g' -e's/,$//'
```

There are some scope files missing in the above command like 'code-manpages.scope', 'grapics-openclipart.scope', 'video-remote.scope', 'video-local.scope', 'help-yelp.scope', 'reference-zotero.scope'

Answer (score 1):

Or use old famous hack with hosts file. In /etc/hosts add following lines

```
127.0.0.1   productsearch.ubuntu.com
127.0.0.1   productsearch.ubuntu.com.home
```

Works in 15.04. If it doesn't help use wireshark to see what host(s) dash trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

From [this tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/how-to-disable-amazon-shopping.html), I have run in [**terminal**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) -

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

And then-

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

And after that-

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Worked for me :)