# Does 12.10 have integration with Amazon?

Tags: amazon

Does Ubuntu 12.10 have integration with Amazon?

I refer to shopping suggestions from Amazon will be plonked into desktop search results, shown when users attempt to find stuff on their computers and the local network.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, Amazon provides a very long range of services. Are you asking whether you can search books from the ubuntu 12.10? If it is able run in their cloud environment?

Comment: Why is Amazon link installed on the sidebar of Ubunto 12.10 in the first place , does Amazon pay to be put here or something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 
12.10 will have integration with Amazon. If you don't like it and you want to remove it, see here how: [How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Another options are to return back to Debian or to look for an alternative like Arch Linux.