# How can I move Amazon search results into a dedicated shopping lens and out of the home lens?

Tags: unity-dash, shopping-lens

I don't want Amazon search results to show up in the home lens and prefer to access them in an independent shopping lens.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mark Tully has created a shopping lens independent of Canonical's unity-lens-shopping.

Search results in the independent lens are still Canonical/Amazon affiliated links and purchases made will help fund Ubuntu.  To install the independent shopping lens simply run the following two commands in the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-shopping-alternate
```

Remove shopping results from the home lens with the terminal command below.  This will uninstall Canonical's default shopping lens.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

Found on [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-install-a-dedicated-amazon-shopping-lens-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You could always completely disable Amazon search results if you open the App "Privacy" and change the Online results to Off:

- [How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash or disable the feature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash)

Though if you want them to be in a separate lens go with the solution of Mark Tully i agree.. :)

---

Warning: *doing this will disable all the online search results. For example, if you have your Google account connected with Ubuntu, it searches even among your drive and Gmail stuff. Turning this off will prevent those searches too.*