# Will Xubuntu also have amazon ads?

Tags: unity-dash, applications-lens

I've been reading on the news, forums, and different websites that the new version in 12.10, which i'll eventually have to upgrade to if I plan on using Ubuntu, has a lens/amazon function on the dash that sends queries to amazon. Now, this disturbs me a bit, since I don't want to see "shopping recommendations" everytime I look for something, be they from amazon or from "future partners".

Does this new "function" only apply to the Unity desktop? If I switch to the Xfce desktop, will I be able to "save myself" from sending search data to amazon and/or shopping recommendations from them? Or will I have to entirely switch distributions, in order to evade this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Amazon ads are specifically part of the Unity shell. Xubuntu uses the Xfce desktop, not Unity; Xfce provides its own panel and run dialog. So yes, the feature will *not* be activated when running an Xfce session.

Alternatively, it's possible to use Unity with the Amazon search results disabled: [How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash or disable the feature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash).

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I sometimes forget that it is, after all, Linux, and we have the option of turning things on and off. I guess I was overly impressed by all the media articles regarding this subject.