# Ubuntu 12.04 Spyware: What to Do?

Tags: 12.04

> Ubuntu uses the information about searches to show the user ads to buy
>   various things from Amazon. Amazon commits many wrongs (see
>   http://stallman.org/amazon.html); by promoting Amazon, Canonical
>   contributes to them. However, the ads are not the core of the problem.
>   The main issue is the spying. Canonical says it does not tell Amazon
>   who searched for what. However, it is just as bad for Canonical to
>   collect your personal information as it would have been for Amazon to
>   collect it.
>
> http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/ubuntu-spyware.html

Same question has been asked here [Ubuntu with spyware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226575/ubuntu-with-spyware) But I don't have the tab 'search results' on my 12.04 distro. How can I disable this?

I understand that canonical uses this business plan in order to make a living and I really would help in their research as long as the data is preserved anonymously, but I really want to have control over this option, so when I search for something to buy, then enable it so I can help canonical gather this data, otherwise I would like this option disabled.

Thank you

Comment: I don't want to remove! I want to locate the option in order to enable or disable

Comment: As [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/347418/25656) indicates, your concerns are unfounded at least for 12.04. In any case, **do read** http://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash because it has advice on "enable or disable" as well making your question a possible duplicate for those versions of Ubuntu that do indeed implement Amazon searches..

Comment: Its not a duplicate, 12.04 does not have that as Eero mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon search results were included in Ubuntu 12.10, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: 12.04 does not have this 'feature' anymore? or it does not exist as an option at all but still exists as an action for ubuntu someware hard coded?

Comment: It never has exisited in 12.04 it was introduced in 12.10 as stated If you are using 12.04 you don't have to worry about the amazon lens

Comment: that would be the answer to my problem.