# How to get access to Search Results tab in Privacy Settings?

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, privacy

My problem:
I wanted to disable the Unity shopping lens on dash. The solution proposed here by Salem seemed simple.
[Ubuntu with spyware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226575/ubuntu-with-spyware)
However, my privacy settings does not have the "Search Results" tab on it.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

My question:
How can I get the Search Options tab to show up under privacy settings so that way I may be able to disable the Unity shopping lens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://fixubuntu.com/ 
but note, The privacy problems started with 12.10, so earlier versions should do nothing.