# much background traffic

Tags: background-process, traffic

Since I am working with Dist. 13.04 I am experiencing much background traffic. I have a monthly limit of GB to down or upload. So it is burdening my balance.
What I have done up to now:
1. I have switched of Ubuntu One from automatically synchronizing. But it showed no improvement.
2. I switch on and off my internet connection according to my work. So I just have connection if I want to work in the internet. That has reduced heavily the daily background traffic balance but it is nasty. It wasn't necessary before. I could stay online all the time without much background down/upload.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

[How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash or disable the feature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash)

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

Comment: hth thanks, I have removed it. But I don't work under Unity. I prefere GNOME. Then lens-shopping as well was active? Okay I have remoed it. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a command line utility called nethogs to help identify programs using bandwidth. `sudo apt-get install nethogs` There also a program called trickle in the repos that can limit bandwidth used. `sudo apt-get install trickle`

[Trickle HowTo](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/01/how-i-manage-bandwidth-using-trickle-on-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Scott Goodgame thanks! have installed both and will try to work with them. Maybe after some time Ill know more about my background traffic.

Comment: meanwhile I have tried it with EtherApe. It shows better my traffic. As my balance has improved the last days, I'll try to stay online again and see, what happens. I'll come back then.

Comment: still the same: if I stay online all the time, then the down- and uploads are many (about 700-900 MB per day), but in the background. Or how is it with Twitter? I have started to use it to publish news, which I get to followers. Per day I receive and send about 60-100 tweets.