# Will Canonical disable Amazon (and similar) lenses by default

Tags: unity, configuration, security, unity-dash, lenses

I'm using 12.04 LTS, partially because it's stable and I need my machine to be stable and reliable. I also don't wont to switch to newer versions of Ubuntu because of shopping lenses. If I decide  to install newer version of Linux I'll go for Linux Mint Debian Edition. I know that this lenses can be disabled or completely removed, but it makes me frustrated. Linux was once famous for speed, stability and security, now Canonical drives Ubuntu off that course. I also understand that these lenses can be useful to someone, but at least ask us (users) about that on first start-up. Or even better disable it by default.

Also, even if I want to keep that feature, I don't want them all in one. I mean, if I want to search my local files I don't want to search the internet at the same time. I know this can also be tweaked, but why not make it default?

I also decided not to support Ubuntu Edge because of this.

So, may question is : Will Canonical disable Amazon (and similar) lenses by default in some future releases?

This question is also appeal for Canonical, please hear your users!

Please make it configurable as possible. Make detailed options for what is searched by default when I press Super (is it local files, apps, amazon, facebook etc or some combination of them).

Then it would be really great.

(Sorry for that proposal at the end, I don't know how to address to Canonical other way.)

Comment: Well you can choose not to use Unity...

Comment: It's very simple to remove it: [How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash). And personaly I'm happy because is installed by default ;). So, your question is **primarily opinion-based**.

Comment: Since amazon probably backs/funds Canonical in order to have their own lenses, I don't see them doing that anytime soon.

Comment: OK, I understand. I just love Ubuntu, I love that approach to business and "ordinary" users. I'm not even saying that this cannot be good thing. But at least, I'd like Canonical make it as configurable as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask me, I don't believe, that those features will be disabled in the future. For that reason they are there, and Canonical thinks they are convenient. Most users don't bother, or think they are positive.
If you don't think so, you might change distro. There are many good distros with another philosophy and not ALL Linux Distros have to say a loud NO to business. I think that's not fair.
Well, I uninstall those lenses and do also some other things to protect myself against advertising and data collection.