# How can I disable these advertisements in the launcher in 14.10?

Tags: unity, launcher, 14.10

This looks like a great launcher (although I can't tell what the name of it is. Please edit this question and title to reflect its real name if you like).

I wanted to run Sublime Text.

How can I remove these advertisements from my launcher search results?

Please Canonical, don't enable this stuff by default. It's awful and unexpected. I was curious and clicked through, and regretted it. Feels gross.

---

Great answers from 3 years ago over at [How can I remove Amazon search results from the dash or disable the feature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192269/how-can-i-remove-amazon-search-results-from-the-dash-or-disable-the-feature)

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can change your privacy settings through "security and privacy"when searching in the Dash "off"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System settings > Security & privacy > choose the Search Tab, uncheck "include internet results":

[image]

(Always the first thing I do after a fresh install :))

Comment: i think the screenshot has to be in English for AskUbuntu