# I messed up my Ubuntu 17.04 (Unity) UI - presumably due to removing some Gnome apps and using autoremove. How do I fix this?

Tags: unity, package-management, gui, 17.04

I'm a complete Linux newbie who installed Ubuntu 17.04 (Unity) on his DELL XPS 15 9560 laptop - and subsequently after a bit of playing around messed up the UI.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

As you can see, the folders list on the left is very tightly packed now, as well as the *ThemeIconsCursorFonts* tabs in the Unity Tweak Tool on the right.

Moreover, the drop down menus for the fonts there aren't visually distinct from the background anymore.

This all looked just fine until I somehow messed something up.

Being used from Windows 10 to first of all uninstall a bunch of crap (like games) after a clean install, I `sudo apt remove`-d a few gnome things that I *thought* would be safe to kill, like `gnome-sudoku` and a few others, and then went `sudo apt autoremove`, which to my surprise seemed to wipe away quite a few packages.

Any idea how I can recover whatever it is that I messed up here?

Comment: Please note with Linux you usually don't have to remove much extra - extra packages aren't as big as they rely on generic system libraries, and there isn't much in the first place (though there was the exception that it used have weird shopping 'scopes', see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/192269/178596)). My inital reaction would be try and reinstall the relevant desktop metapackage which may be `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` but I am not sure if this would work (be careful). Your issue looks to be more theme dependent though, which one are you using?

Comment: I think you may have been correct there. I used `arc-dark-solid` but it seems that was broken. Now I just changed to `arc-theme` and it looks fine again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Wilf pointed out in the comments - it seems this was a theme issue, not one caused by missing packages.

I changed from `arc-dark-solid` to `arc-theme` and now it looks okay.