# Is privacy an issue while searching in the Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, privacy

I have hear that user's IP addresses and search terms can be shared with Amazon, Facebook, Vimeo and others services , is it true ?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu? You mean Dash searches?

Comment: Look on the right-hand side of this page under "Related". You'll find a lot of questions like yours which have already been answered. As far as possible, do search the site to find if your question has already been answered. If it has, it saves you the trouble of having to draft an entirely new question.

Comment: To me this falls into: `What kind of questions should I not ask here?
<..> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Your questions should be reasonably scoped`. Factual answer would be either yes or no. All other related discussions should be done elsewhere (like on mark shuttleworths blog ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind "Yes/no, because..." with references would, as always, be a good factual answer. This question is definitely appropriate for our site, though we might be able to find something to dupe it to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will all Dash input in 12.10 be sent to Amazon?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191897/will-all-dash-input-in-12-10-be-sent-to-amazon)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is true; I feel this could not be repeated enough. 
The searches include mostly your string that you gave in in the Dash. When the Dash couldn't find an answer it gives it out to tirth parties like (commonly known) Amazon. 
This idea was implemented NOT to spy on you, but just letting the Dash give you always an answer, even when the thing you were searching for is not on your computer.

It's sad this option got green light, but look at it as an extra feature (and don't get to paranoïd about it).

You can easily disable this feature using the Privacy settings:

[image]

In 13.04 you should be able to choose to enable some providers while disabling others.

Comment: You can opt-out of this in 12.10, I did. The difference between 12.10 and 13.04 is that in 13.04 you can disable or enable each provider and in 12.10 it's all or nothing.

Comment: Note that you should be careful giving this kind of wrong and controversial answers, I was tempted to vote you down, but I realised that a simple edit will be much more useful for other users.

Comment: Hey guys slow down on me a little , i am totally new to the idea of using linux and ubuntu and the open source programs etc... but thank you very much your replies have really helped me .

Answer (score 3):

If you mean searching in dash,Yes your searches will be send to canonical servers without warning or explicit approval . But privacy is depends on the perspective, Some people thinks it is a privacy issue,and some people don't. Any way you can optout this feature